# Extend django permissions for specific group of users

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Coach(User):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    branding = models.CharField(choices=BRANDINGS)

class Patient(User):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    branding = models.CharField(choices=BRANDINGS)
```

Is there any way to allow coaches see patients only of their branding? I think writing filter queryset on each view is a bad idea. Mayby it can be done by changing permissions?

Comment: No, queryset is the only good idea in your case.

Comment: you can get brand from coach and than get patient wrt that brand, b=Coach.Objects.get(id=1).branding  ,   and  ,  patientslist = Patients.objects.filter(branding = b) , well again its on usecase what you actually want

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you create a coach-patient relationship?

It would look something like this:

```
class Coach(User):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    branding = models.CharField(choices=BRANDINGS)

class Patient(User):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    coach = model.ForignKey(Coach, related_name='Patient')
```

In this way, just add in view choach.patient.all() search to find all patients of a certain coach